# Openss7 - cloneopen() function

Tags: c++, c

I am trying to explore the `openss7` driver module for future enhancements, but when I tried, I couldn't find where the `cloneopen` function is getting called.

```
openss7/src/drivers/clone.c:216:cloneopen(struct inode *inode, struct file *file)
```

Where is it called?

Comment: Yes, I looked at the line, but cannot find where this function getting called.

Comment: @TobiMcNamobi: That's the declaration.

Comment: Download the source and grep it?

Comment: I have already tried Tobi, but no luck.

Comment: https://github.com/openss7/openss7/tree/master/src/drivers

Comment: Just search the source code for the text "cloneopen". Not hard!!!